# Not able to start MySQL, using Xampp v3.2.1, MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, mediawiki

I have installed XAMPP for several weeks, everything was working.
Today i have installed Microsoft Net. Framework 4.
After this Apache shut down and i could not run it. MySQL was running.
I have uninstalled XAMPP, restarted computer and installed XAMPP again to C:/xampp.

Now things goes oppositely. Apache is running. MySQL shuts down unexpectedly.

I try to run MediaWiki setup, it breaks at MySQL configuration step: "DB connection error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (localhost).
Check the host, username and password and try again. "

What should be done?

The error message which i am getting now:

```
6:46:21 PM  [mysql]     Problem detected!
6:46:21 PM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\MySQL55\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\MySQL55\my.ini" MySQL_ZendServer55"!
6:46:21 PM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
6:46:21 PM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
6:46:21 PM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

regards,
gintare

Comment: First try to connect mysql by any external utility like sqlyog, mysqladministrator etc. with host as locahost, user as root and its password. If you are not able to connect and get same message it means you are using wrong password for root.

Answer (score 0):

Usually MySQL doesnt accept connections on localhost but on 127.0.0.1, I know they both should represent the same thing but for MySQL they are different. Try to connecto to mysql using MySQL Workbench or some other tool and specify 127.0.0.1 as the host, if that works just change the connection host for the application you try to run.

Comment: It was working for me all half year around from 2013 October. I am not able to connect from yesterday morning after installing microsoft net framework 4.

Comment: What do you mean by "Try to connecto to mysql using MySQL Workbench"?

Comment: One more way is to remove "microsoft net framework 4" from control panel, "unistall a programm".

Comment: Ans in the same "control panel"-> "unistall a program" it is possible to remove Zend, which use port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed Zend Server and MySQL5.5 using  "control panel"-> "unistall a program". After this MySQL and Apache in XAMPP works.